# Spring Sleuth Tracer not there in spring-cloud-sleuth - What is the alternative?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have used `org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.Tracer` (1.3.x) to get the current Span and Trace ids. It looks like the 2.x releases of `spring-cloud-sleuth-core` got rid of it and after a lot of search no replacement is obvious. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sleuth 2.x was built on top of [Brave](https://github.com/openzipkin/brave). You can check the [1.3 -> 2.x Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-2.0-Migration-Guide) to see how to migrate.

To answer your exact question: Sleuth's Tracer was replaced to `brave.Tracer`, you can inject and use it.

Please notice that Sleuth 3.x has been already released, there is a [2.x -> 3.x Migration-Guide](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-3.0-Migration-Guide). In 3.0, Sleuth abstracts the tracing libraries away so there is a Sleuth Tracer in 3.x.

I suggest to upgrade to the latest version of Sleuth (this also means upgrading to the lates Spring Boot and Spring Cloud too).

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out.